# Python: ImportError: No module named 'tutorial.quickstart'

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I am getting import error even when I am following the tutorial http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/quickstart/  line by line.

```
from tutorial.quickstart import views
```

> ImportError: No module named 'tutorial.quickstart'

**where my urls.py file looks like**

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from rest_framework import routers
from tutorial.quickstart import views

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', views.UserViewSet)
router.register(r'groups', views.GroupViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
        url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework'))
]
```

Note: I have the project in Rest_Tutorial folder which consist of virtual enviroment - `env` and project `tutorial`. This tutorial consist of `quickstart` and `tutorial`

Comment: Want to show your directory structure?

Comment: Python automatically adds your current directory to the sys path. If the tutorial package is not installed, and it is not in the current directory, try to add it with `sys.path.append('path/to/tutorialpackage')`
Also have a look at similar questions, there were already asked some questions like that.

Answer (score 16):

Change `from tutorial.quickstart import views` to `from quickstart import views` in both `tutorial/url.py` file as well as `tutorial/quickstart/views.py`file. This should work.

This is required as python automatically adds your current directory to sys path.

Answer (score 6):

Just change `tutorial.quickstart import views` to `from quickstart import views` in both **tutorial/url.py** file as well as **tutorial/quickstart/views.py** file.

Answer (score 4):

USE:

`django-admin startproject tutorial .`

INSTEAD of:

`django-admin startproject tutorial`

while you start the project.

It is mentioned in the documentation.(Read carefully)

Comment: The trailing dot(.) in creating the project are easy to be ignored. If it's ignored, the tutorial import in Quickstart/views.py and tutorial/urls.py should be adjusted from `from tutorial.quickstart` to `from quickstart` as said in other response.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your tutorial.quickstart is in the same folder as your project.
Also make sure it is unzipped ! Otherwise use a absolute path.

Hope it helps !

Comment: well everything is perfect, but your suggestion has given me an idea to try-out.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `from quickstart import views` instead of `from tutorial.quickstart import views` if you use PyCharm or other IDE. And don't forget change code where use  `from tutorial.quickstart.[xxx] import [xxx]`.

Answer (score 1):

In quickstart/views.py: 
    from .serializers import UserSerializer, GroupSerializer
in tutorial/urls.py:

```
from quickstart import views
```

That worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

It **works** for me by modification tow importing files

- /tutorial/quickstart/views.py

`from tutorial.quickstart.serializers import UserSerializer, GroupSerializer`

to

`from quickstart.serializers import UserSerializer, GroupSerializer`

- /tutorial/urls.py

`from tutorial.quickstart import views`

to

`from quickstart import views`

Answer (score 0):

i was getting this issues several times,

with-

python version`3.6.9`

django version`3.2.14` and

restframework`3.13.1`

so, first step:

i just updated the python version to `3.9.13` and django version to  `4.0.6` and restframework version was same as before.

second step:

Change `from tutorial.quickstart import views` to `from quickstart import views` in `tutorial/urls.py` file

as well as if you write

`from serializers import UserSerializer, GroupSerializer`

or

`from tutorials.quickstart.serializers import UserSerializer, GroupSerializer`

in `tutorial/quickstart/views.py` file then you can change it to

`from quickstart.serializers import UserSerializer, GroupSerializer` or `from .serializers import UserSerializer, GroupSerializer`.

Hopefully, This should work.